# Scala Regex UDF to grab query parameter values and transform them into comma delimited list

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, udf

I have data that looks similar to the following:

```
one=1&two=22222&three=&four=4f4
```

As you can see, the value for the variable three is missing. I would like to use Scala Regex to grab all the values and return them comma delimited.

Desired Output:

```
1,22222,,4f4
```

Another, More Desired, Possible Output:

```
1,22222,undefined,4f4
```

This is my current code (I am using scala with Spark 2.0 for a dataframe):

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  ...
  val pattern : scala.util.matching.Regex = """[^&?]*?=([^&?]*)""".r
  df.select(transform(pattern)($"data").alias("csvData")).take(100).foreach(println)
}

def transform(pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex) = udf(
 (dataMapping: String) => pattern.findAllIn(dataMapping).toList
)
```

Which returns:

```
[WrappedArray(one=1, two=22222, three=, four=4f4)]
[WrappedArray(...)]
```

I think I can do better on my "transform" udf function, but I am very new to Scala and am unsure of how to just match the first groups and return them comma separated. I would guess I would use something like m => m.group(1) in my solution, but I'm not sure. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple columns you would probably be best off using a `UDF`:

```
scala> val df = Seq(("one=1&two=22222&three=&four=4f4", 1)).toDF("a", "b")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: string, b: int]

scala> df.show
+--------------------+---+
|                   a|  b|
+--------------------+---+
|one=1&two=22222&t...|  1|
+--------------------+---+

scala> val p = """[one|two|three|four]\=([\d|\W|\w]+)""".r
p: scala.util.matching.Regex = [one|two|three|four]\=([\d|\W|\w]+)

scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val regexUDF = udf( (x: String) =>
    x.split("&").map(p.findFirstMatchIn(_).map(_.group(1)).getOrElse(null)))
    )

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

regexUDF: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,ArrayType(StringType,true),Some(List(StringType)))

scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("a", regexUDF($"a"))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: array<string>, b: int]   

scala> df2.show
+--------------------+---+
|                   a|  b|
+--------------------+---+
|[1, 22222, null, ...|  1|
+--------------------+---+


scala> df2.collect.foreach{println}
[WrappedArray(1, 22222, null, 4f4),1]
```

Comment: Is there a way to have just the 1, 22222... in the value column instead of including the column names and = signs?

Comment: Also, if the dataframe has many columns, how do I specify that I want to split on the column called data?

Comment: I really like where you're going with that last example. When I run it, I get error script.scala:43: error: not found: value p.

Comment: You will need the regex pattern I defined before. If this is a distributed cluster you may need to broadcast the pattern. Stay tuned, I am working on better regex parsing

Comment: would it be possible to share with me what the code in the transform method would be if I wanted to keep everything else the same with only changing the details between the parenthesis of udf? I simplified my example quite a bit an am having trouble converting your examples to my code.

Comment: Better regex handling added. I am not quite sure what you are asking, does my `String => Array` mapping within the udf not work as required?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128105/discussion-between-evan058-and-satoukum).